# How can i push an array to another array to make a 2 level array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

it might sound confusing though my goal is to make an array like this.

```
var array2D= [
    { locations: [0, 0, 0], status: ["", "", ""] },
    { locations: [0, 0, 0], status: ["", "", ""] },
    { locations: [0, 0, 0], status: ["", "", ""] }
],
```

so consider if i have arrays like below.

```
var locations = [0,0,0];
var status = ["","",""];
```

can i somehow push them to make a 2d array?
i tried something like this but it doesn't work

```
var the2Darray =[];
the2Darray.push(location,status);
```

Comment: The thing you're trying to make is not a 2D array.

Comment: You need to clarify part of the logic for this question to get answered: For example, why do you get 3 lines in the final array, why not 2? Also this is not a 2D array technically, it's a bunch of objects in a 1D array...

Comment: Actually you want to create an array of objects such that each object have locations and status attributes, both of which are arrays.

Comment: apparently i got it wrong, thanks for the answer guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var locations = [0,0,0];
var status = ["","",""]; 
var the2Darray =[];
the2Darray.push({locations: locations,status: status});
```

Comment: thanks a lot! it works like a charm. seems i got the wrong logic

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an object with keys as locations and status assigning them corresponding array, then simply push to your new array.

```
var 2dArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < lengthYouWant; i++) {
    var locations = [1,2,3];
    var status = ["a", "b", "c"];
    var obj = {locations : locations, status : status};
    2dArray.push(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, you want independent arrays, than you need to use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for a copy of [primitive types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive), like string, number, boolean, null, undefined, symbol (new in ECMAScript 2015).

```js
var locations = [0, 0, 0],
    status = ["", "", ""];
    array = [],
    l = 3;

while (l--) {
    array.push({ locations: locations.slice(), status: status.slice() });
}

array[2].locations[0] = 42;

console.log(array)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

What happpens, if not using splice, please have a look to `42`.

As you will see, all arrays of `locations` and `status` shares the same reference to the original array.

```js
var locations = [0, 0, 0],
    status = ["", "", ""];
    array = [],
    l = 3;

while (l--) {
    array.push({ locations: locations, status: status });
}

array[2].locations[0] = 42;

console.log(array)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: this is rather a little complex, but it seems elegant, i'll try it later thanks!